# MongoDB Aggregation Framework: Getting $unwind error when using $group

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a document structure as follows:

```
{
  "_id" : NumberLong("80000000012"),
[...]
  "categories" : [{
      "parent" : "MANUFACTURER",
      "category" : "Chevrolet"
    }, {
      "parent" : "MISCELLANEOUS",
      "category" : "Miscellaneous"
    }],
[...]
}
```

I am trying to get a distinct list of all 'category' fields for each 'parent' field.  I was trying to utilize the aggregation framework to do this with the following query:

```
db.posts_temp.aggregate(
    {$unwind : '$categories'},
    {$match : {'categories.parent' : 'MISCELLANEOUS'}},
    {$project : {
        '_id' : 0,
        parent : '$categories.parent',
        category : '$categories.category'
        }
    },
    {
        $group : { 
            _id : '$parent',
            category : {$addToSet : '$category'}
        }
    }
);
```

Running this query returns the following error:

```
{
    "errmsg" : "exception: $unwind:  value at end of field path must be an array",
    "code" : 15978,
    "ok" : 0
}
```

This seems to be tied to the group portion of the query, because, when I remove it, the query runs correctly, but, obviously, the data is not where I want it to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried executing the above aggregation query on my mongo instance. Here are my 3 documents each with a key of categories that has an array of two nested documents.

Here is my data:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("512d5252b748191fefbd4698"),
    "categories" : [
        {
            "parent" : "MANUFACTURER",
            "category" : "Chevrolet"
        },
        {
            "parent" : "MISCELLANEOUS",
            "category" : "Miscellaneous"
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("512d535cb748191fefbd4699"),
    "categories" : [
        {
            "parent" : "MANUFACTURER",
            "category" : "Chevrolet"
        },
        {
            "parent" : "MISCELLANEOUS",
            "category" : "Pickup"
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("512d536eb748191fefbd469a"),
    "categories" : [
        {
            "parent" : "MANUFACTURER",
            "category" : "Toyota"
        },
        {
            "parent" : "MISCELLANEOUS",
            "category" : "Miscellaneous"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is the aggregation query of yours that I ran:

```
db.posts_temp.aggregate( {$unwind:'$categories'} , {$match: {'categories.parent':'MISCELLANEOUS'}}, {$project:{'_id':0, parent: '$categories.parent', category:'$categories.category'}}, {$group:{_id:'$parent', category:{$addToSet:'$category'}}})
```

Here is the result:

```
{
    "result" : [
        {
            "_id" : "MISCELLANEOUS",
            "category" : [
                "Pickup",
                "Miscellaneous"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Let me know if there some discrepancies between my data and yours.

CSharpie

Comment: We ran this again at work and moved the match statement ahead of the unwind and that fixed it. Our best guess was that the unwind creating some kind of in memory collection that was too big and threw an error.  We have about 18k documents in the collection. *shrug*

Comment: ^What he said.  Thanks for looking.